# Laravel: How to get map of countires states using antonioribeiro/countries package?

Tags: laravel, maps, states, countries

With [antonioribeiro/countries](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries) package I get a list of states (Serbia) in table like this:

```
$countries = Countries::where('name.common', 'Serbia')
    ->first()
    ->hydrateStates()
    ->states
    ->sortBy('name')
    ->pluck('name', 'postal');

return view('countries.index', compact('countries'));
```

Is there a method to get a map with states borders in country map? Like this for example:

[image: Serbia regions]

In first page inf it has Geology and topology maps butI can't find this in docs.

Comment: All topological maps are provided as [json objects here](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/countries/tree/master/src/data/topo). These do not contain the state names, just the borders.

Comment: Is there another package or something else that I can use for this if this won't work?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that answer. Is there a reason that Google Maps won't work for you?

Comment: Google maps would be great but also I can't find regions for Serbia. I searched here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart . Is there something else?

Comment: I found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584788/googlechart-geochart-french-region-map?rq=1 but if I try change FR into RS it shows Serbia map but with only 3 regions even it has 29...